# Print words using string module and ascii in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, ascii

I was curious about how ASCII worked in python, so I decided to find out more. I learnt quite a bit, before I began to try to print letters using ASCII numbers. I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly, as I am using the string module, but I keep picking up an error

```
print(string.ascii_lowercase(104))
```

This should print out "h", as far as I know, but all that happens is that I receive an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    string.ascii_lowercase(104)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

If someone could help me solve this, or tell me a better way, I would be ever grateful. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is `chr`

```
>>> chr(104)
'h'
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

`ascii_lowercase` is a string, not a function. Use `chr(104)`.

Answer (score 1):

The chr() function returns the corresponding character to the ASCII value you put in.

The ord() function returns the ASCII value of the character you put in.

Example:

```
chr(104) = 'h'
ord('h') = 104
```